# Render in Eevee with default skyboxes? ("Scene World' ticked off in Viewport Shading)

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, scene, world, skybox

[image]

How can I render using these skyboxes?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can

Comment: :( but they already have it thereeee, that's so sad
Not even with workbench? In 2.81

Comment: Thank you! yes, that's what I was looking for! I saw that answer before but as I was in a rush earlier I didn't quite gave it a try.